# How should I config the my.ini(or my.cnf) file for mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench

Thanks for taking your time to look at my question, and I hope that you can help me with this.

**I have a Windows Server 2012 server, it has:**

```
Memory : 3840MB Ram

Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.8GHz
```

But still mysql is going up to 100% cpu usage I ran the MySQLInstanceConfig.exe configuration Wizard to help me config everything for mysql and this is the my.ini config file that it created:

```
[client]

port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=latin1

[mysqld]

The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"

datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/data/"

character-set-server=latin1

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max_connections=100

query_cache_size=0

table_cache=256

tmp_table_size=192M

thread_cache_size=8

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=384M

key_buffer_size=332M

read_buffer_size=64K read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

sort_buffer_size=256K

* INNODB Specific options *
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=14M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=7M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=643M

innodb_log_file_size=65M

innodb_thread_concurrency=8
```

But Something is still wrong, it's taking to much CPU

Answer (score 1):

Percona has an extremely awesome [wizard](https://tools.percona.com/wizard) for initial server configuration files (I've used it on our own extremely busy production servers). It requires registration, but usage is free.